Avoid checking concurrency safe that runs in development mode - Swift 6 migration
I am migrating to Swift 6 and I have a macro that we use in development mode. I would like to either avoid or ignore this concurrency check:
This is the code:
    private func setupPubNubLogs() {
        #if ENV_DEVELOPMENT
            PubNub.log.levels = [.warn, .error]
            PubNub.log.writers = [ConsoleLogWriter()]
        #endif
    }

This is the error I got:

Is there a good way to ignore these error?
I am using xcode 16 with swift 6. PubNub is a third-party library.
I tried to put it in a Task { @MainActor in } but it did not work.
